# Vertically Panning a Google Column Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, chap-links-library

Is there any JavaScript out there or examples for horizontally panning a Google Column Chart?
I have several months worth of data and I would like the users to be able to view it left to right. This is the functionality I would like: http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/graph/examples/example05_gaps_in_data.html.  My users have pushed back against using an Annotated TimeLine.

Answer (score 5):

You can hook a ColumnChart up to a [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) and get the pan and zoom functionality of the AnnotatedTimeline.

[Edit]

The new version of the Visualization API supports zooming and panning charts via the `explorer` [option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options).  The default allows users to zoom with the scroll wheel and pan by clicking and dragging.  Here's an example:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
    var y = 50;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        y += Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3) * Math.pow(-1, Math.floor(Math.random() * 2));
        data.addRow([i, y]);
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        explorer: {
            axis: 'horizontal',
            keepInBounds: true
        }
    });
}
google.load('visualization',
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/KArng/

Comment: Could you provide more information or a link to some sample code? Ideally I'd like to just use my mouse to pan; my boss doesn't like the adjustable box control.

Comment: Clicking and dragging on the chart to pan is theoretically possible, but could be difficult to implement well.  I'll have to think about this a bit.

Comment: Good news: the API now supports zooming and panning without additional controls.  Updated my post with an example.

Comment: also in case you do not seem to see the explorer working, note that the function only works with continuous data such as numbers and dates

Answer (score 0):

Ironically the library I referenced is actually using Google Visualization charts and doing some amazing things with them, including panning.

Comment: They are using the Visualization API to handle the data end of things, but the chart appears to be from another chart library.

Comment: Yes I see that now. Back to square one.